# SQL Replace Not working for Greater Than >

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to count all values in a column `Value` that are over 5.

However, some results in that column appear like '>10' (it has the greater than symbol `>` in the field)

I'd like to still count that as > 5.

To do that, I did the following:

```
(COUNT(CASE WHEN t.VALUE LIKE '*>*'
        and Replace(t.VALUE, '>', ' ') > 5)
Then 1
Else NULL
End
)
```

But, for whatever reason, it's not replacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.

The asterisk isn't a valid wildcard character in SQL Server, so we'll change that.

Also, if you want the string to become a number, you'll want to replace the greater-than with an empty string, not a space. It doesn't affect the outcome, but it's the right thing to do.

This isn't as elegant as Gordon's one-liner, but it produced the expected results.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (VALUE VARCHAR(5));
INSERT @t (VALUE)
VALUES ('1'),('10'),('>10');

SELECT COUNT(*) AS Over5
FROM
  (
    SELECT
     CASE WHEN t.VALUE LIKE '%>%' THEN Replace(t.VALUE, '>', '')
         ELSE t.VALUE
     END AS NewVal
    FROM @t as t
  ) AS d
WHERE NewVal > 5;

+-------+
| Over5 |
+-------+
|     2 |
+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely skipped the whole wildcard issue, since I copied it off crystal. However, in addition to '>', I'm also using '%' as something I'd like to replace. Considering `%` is used as a wildcard in SQL, how could  I replace it?

Comment: Happy to help. Just escape the '%' with square brackets. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals

Comment: thanks for the help. Last point: When I run with the changes above, I get the following error: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '14.0' to data type int.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.`

Comment: ' THEN CAST(Replace(t.VALUE, '>', '') AS numeric(<Scale>,<Precision>))  '  Just set the scale and precision to work with your data.

Answer (score 2):

Well, how about converting to a number?

```
select sum(case when try_convert(int, replace(t.value, '>', '')) > 5
                then 1 else 0
           end) as values_over_5
```

Your data model is suspicious, because you are doing numeric comparisons on a column that contains numbers.